# what is wrong with this code it says listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 127.0.0.1:8080

Tags: javascript, node.js

this is the code it does not run on any port not just 8080

```
var http = require('http');

  function func(req, res){
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
      res.end('Hello form node.js');
  }

  http.createServer(func).listen(32064, '127.0.0.1');
```

Comment: where are you running this code  ? or your local server or some cloud ?

Comment: there's a zombie process - run `ps aux | grep npm` (replace npm if you started the app with something else) and then `kill -9 << pid >>` where `<< pid >>` is the process id from the `ps aux` command

Comment: Most likely you are running this code on some cloud machine as normally we don't have such issues when working on local machine. So, what I would suggest is to replace port number with `process.env.PORT || you_port`

Answer (score 1):

Strange because your code is using the port 32064:

`server.listen(port, address)`

Anyway, a socket is already listening on your port. The best way to find which process is using the socket, use lsof or netstat:

`lsof -i :8080
or
netstat -lntp | grep '8080'`